# Swift : Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(@noescape (Int) throws -> Bool)'

Tags: swift

I am stuck with this error:

```
func compactCoords(coords: [Int]) -> [Int]{
    return coords.filter({ (value) -> Bool in
        return value != 0
    })
}
```

Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(@noescape (Int) throws -> Bool)'

Thanks for your help!

Comment: To help you here I need a bit more context. How do you invoke the function? The last time I had this error I tried to apply the returned array of the filter function to a set. So maybe you get the error because of the way you invoke that function...

Comment: Tony Stark thanks. That helped me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine in Xcode 7.1. You might be accidentally trying to run this code in Xcode 6.x?

You can shorten your function like this:

```
func compactCoords(coords: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    return coords.filter { $0 != 0 }
}
```

Output:

```
let coords = [1,2,3,0,4,5,6]
let compactedCoords = compactCoords(coords) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```